# Simulate Python Mouse Click win 8.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, winapi

From work i got a job to make a python script which will click for testing the product of a "secret application" for windows 8.1. 
The problem is that i can make it move the cursor but it can't click and i searched for win32 documentation on the internet but with no luck. Anyone who had this problem?
This is the click code

```
 def click(x,y):
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y)) 
        #Left click
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
        time.sleep(0.05)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

Comment: The sleep is pointless. I can't imagine why you added that. You should do this with one call to SendInput.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Yes, i thought the mouse events were to fast.

Comment: You didn't check for errors. Did you read the documentation closely?

Comment: You are passing relative coords. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes i am sending relative coords, there are 20 cases in an array and i am moving the mouse all over them. The moving works perfectly the click doesn't. Documentation is very limited and i didn't understand nothing from it.

Comment: So you want to place the cursor at x,y and then click at x,y relative to that? If you don't understand the documentation, you aren't ready to proceed. Don't you think it will help to understand before continuing. I don't think you even read it. Did you not notice where it told you not to call mouse_event and call SendInput instead? Did you really read all about relative vs absolute. Please let me commend another read of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly with ctypes on my Windows 8.1 laptop

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(500, 500)
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0,0) #left down
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0,0) #left up
```

Comment: Correct API to use if you insist on faking input: [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx). Appropriate procedure to automate a UI: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can install the PyAutoGUI GUI automation module from PyPI (run `pip install pyautogui`) and then call the `pyautogui.click()` to click on a certain X and Y coordinates of the screen:

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> pyautogui.click(50, 100)
```

PyAutoGUI works on Windows, Mac, and Linux, and on Python 2 and 3. It also can emulate the keyboard, do mouse drags, take screenshots, and do simple image recognition of the screenshots. Full docs are at https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/